# On an inequality for the arithmetic function counting the number of primes $\lfloor n^c\rfloor$ in the spirit of Ramanujan's prime counting inequality

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, inequalities, asymptotics

In page 3 of [1] (please see if you need it the book by Berndt) Axler refers an inequality that involves the prime-counting function $\pi(x)$ and that was deduced by Ramanujan. I'm curious to know if it is possible to deduce, or if it is in the literature, a similar inequality for the arithmetic function $\pi_c(x)$ that counts the number of primes $\lfloor n^c\rfloor$, when the integer $n$ runs over the interval $1\leq n\leq x$ and $0<c\leq 1$ is a fixed real constant. Here thus $\lfloor y\rfloor$ is the floor function.

Let $c$ a fixed positive real number $c\leq 1$ (my comparisons were from the remarks of first paragraph in page 59 of [2], thus Exercise 1.35), we denote with $\pi_c(x)$ the arithmetic function that counts the number of primes of the form $\lfloor n^c\rfloor$ when the integers $n$ run over the interval $[1,x]$ (again same page and exercise of [2]), then I wrote

$$\pi_c(x)^2<c\cdot \frac{ex}{\log x}\pi_c(\frac{x}{e})\tag{1}$$

> **Question.**  I would like to know if it is possible to deduce a similar Ramanujan's prime counting inequality for primes $\lfloor n^c\rfloor$ (that's an inequality involving the particular values of the arithmetic function $\pi_c(x)$, for $0<c<1$ instead of the particular values of $\pi(x)$ as I've tried in $(1)$). Additionally I would like to know over what interval can be proven (unconditionally or invoking the Riemann hypothesis) your inequality, or mine if my inequality $(1)$ does make sense. **Many thanks.**

As was expressed I don't know if this inequality $(1)$ has a good mathematical content since I've deduced it doing comparisons. I don't know if previous question(s) is in the literature since I don't know if were studied explicit inequalities for the arithmetic function $\pi_c(x)$ as Axler (and the other authors) did in his article (for $c>0$), if you know it from the literature* answer my question as a reference request and I try to search and read the proposition.

### References:

[1] Christian Axler, *Estimates for* $\pi(x)$ *for large values of* $x$ *and Ramanujan's prime counting inequality*, INTEGERS **18**, Article #A61 (2018).

[2] Richard Crandall and Carl Pomerance, *Prime numbers: A computational Perspective*, Springer, Second Edition (2005).

[3] B. C. Berndt, *Ramanujan’s Notebooks, Part IV*, Springer, New York (1994).

Comment: * I know that a similar question is in the literature, the article Mehdi Hassani, *Remarks on Ramanujan’s inequality concerning the prime counting function*, Communications in Mathematics n (20xy) ab–cd, that I can to read from Sciendo in the Internet (I refer the last paragraph of section 4).

Comment: I hope that the question is interesting, as I said I don't know if my inequality $(1)$ makes sense for some remarkable interval.